# Is there a way to specify "shard key" into mongoItemWriter?

Tags: mongodb, spring-batch

I'm really new to spring batch's mongoItemWriter.

I use the MongoItemWriter as below,

```kotlin
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    fun mongoItemWriter(mongoOperations: MongoOperations): MongoItemWriter<MongoWord> {
        return MongoItemWriterBuilder<MongoWord>()
            .collection("word")
            .template(mongoOperations)
            .build()
    }
```

but because my MongoDB cluster is sharded one,
I got an error `Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=61, message='Failed to target upsert by query :: could not extract exact shard key', details={}}].`

Is there any way to set the shard key while using mongoItemWriter?
Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

+) here is my stacktrace

```
exception is com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server host:port. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=61, message='Failed to target upsert by query :: could not extract exact shard key', details={}}]. 
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.DefaultBulkOperations.bulkWriteTo(DefaultBulkOperations.java:324) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:560) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.DefaultBulkOperations.execute(DefaultBulkOperations.java:290) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter.saveOrUpdate(MongoItemWriter.java:171) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5.jar!/:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter.doWrite(MongoItemWriter.java:140) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5.jar!/:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter$1.beforeCommit(MongoItemWriter.java:201) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5.jar!/:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:97) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar!/:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:916) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar!/:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:727) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar!/:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar!/:5.3.17]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
```

p.s - I marked Entity `MongoWord` @Sharded already.

```
@Document("word")
@Sharded(shardKey = ["userId"], shardingStrategy = ShardingStrategy.HASH)
data class MongoWord(
    @Id
    var id: String? = null,
    @Field(name = "user_id")
    var userId = 0L
)
```

Comment: Sharding is (and should be) transparent to Spring Batch, because Spring Batch delegates the write operation to a `mongoOperations` instance. Did you check if this is configurable at the `mongoOperations` level? If you share how you would do that *without* Spring Batch and we conclude that it can be added to Spring Batch, we will consider adding this feature.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Actually, I usually used mongoTemplate's `bulkOps` as following - I'll take a look at `mongoOperations` more and let you know or open an issue on the project if there are any updates. Thank you! ```val bulkOperations = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(
            BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, 
            MongoWord::class.java)
        bulkOperations.insert(words)
        bulkOperations.execute()```

Comment: The code you shared is almost the same as the code of the `MongoItemWriter`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemWriter.java#L161. You can update your question with your findings, and add a message here. Will try to help once that done.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine , nowadays I'm digging into to find the difference between the `MongoItemWriter`'s implementation and the code I attached. When I figure it out, I'll open an issue on the github! Thanks :)